# Remove ads when user makes in-app-purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement the in-app-billing API and make my app without ads when the user buy "Remove ads" in-app-purchase. The problem is I am not sure where to do that. I have a FAB button and adview inside a linierlayout like this:
[image]

and as soon as the user buy the it I will set the adview visibility to GONE so the FAB button goes down.

This is my main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG =  MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ArrayList<String> shoppingListItems;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
private TextView mEmptyTextView;
private ShoppingListAdapter adapter;
private ActionButton actionButton;
private MaterialDialog addItemdialog = null;
private IabHelper mHelper;
private String SKU_REMOVE_ADDS = "remove_adds_sku";
private boolean mIsRemoveAdds = false;
private IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchasedFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error purchasing: " + result);
            return;
        }
        else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_REMOVE_ADDS)) {
            // consume the gas and update the UI
            mIsRemoveAdds = true;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Purchase successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //load ads
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
//set up billing
    String publicKey = "PUBLIC_KEY";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this,publicKey);
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if(!result.isSuccess()){
                //error
                Log.d(TAG,"Proglem setting up in-app Billing: " + result);
            }

            //Horay, IAB is fully set up!
            Log.d(TAG,"Horay, IAB is fully set up!");
        }
    });
    queryPurchasedItems();
}
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    isListEmpty();
    queryPurchasedItems();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}
private void queryPurchasedItems() {
    //check if user has bought "remove adds"
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error here
            }
            else{
                // does the user have the premium upgrade?
                mIsRemoveAdds = inventory.hasPurchase(SKU_REMOVE_ADDS);
                // update UI accordingly
            }
        }
    };
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if(id == R.id.action_remove_adds){
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this,SKU_REMOVE_ADDS,1,mPurchasedFinishedListener,"");
    }
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_adds);
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_adds);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes You can do that @Georgi Koemdzhiev

Comment: I know I can do it, but since I am implementing the in-app-Billing API for the first time it is a little confusing, so here I am, seeking help from people who know way more than I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, your solution is suitable for that kind of scenario. In fact, I've used a similar approach for [my app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=id.ridsatrio.taggr) and it's working fine for multiple IAP transactions.

One suggestion, though. You should persists `mIsRemoveAdds` in your `SharedPreferences` just in case. With that done, you could retrieve the value from `SharedPreferences` when you detect that the device is not connected to the internet (airplane mode, or perhaps just bad reception).

Other than that, your code is good.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was thinking of storing the mIsRemoveAdds in SharedPreferences, but than I thought, that querying the inventory for purchased items stores the purchase in cash and querying it will be fine, I guess, when there is no internet.

Comment: Yeah as I said: *just in case*. Users are (rightfully) picky when it comes to IAP. I'm that kind of people who tend to play safe. ;)

Comment: Thanks, I already followed your suggestion and stored the value in sharedPreferences if the purchase is successful. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem, mate. Good luck with your app!